# CS career - frustrating PR review

Tags: colleagues, work-environment, career-development, computer-science

Edit: I don't understand why I'm being downvoted, all I am doing is asking for advice.

I have been a developer for nearly 10 years, though it's the first time I am in a "tech" company. My previous companies were companies like finance that had a tech department where tech is a cost center, though it doesn't mean the tech standards were any lower, in fact they were even more rigorous than the current company.  So I'm not sure if this is normal or not.

Here is the problem. I raise a PR, my coworkers leaves some comments. I make changes based on the comments. Then coworker leaves more comments, NOT based my new changes but based on the code that didn't change. In other words, they leave comments they could've left the first time, but didn't for whatever reason.

One time after my PR was already merged (with their approval), they mention on my other PR that the merged work should be redone.

I am very frustrated and stressed out about this constant back and forth. It took max 2 days to merge a PR at my former companies. Now it takes a week or more, and it makes it look like I'm not getting any work done.

My coworkers question even small things like I made a separate file to keep similar utility functions, which would've been a best practice at my former teams. What makes it even harder is this team has NO best practice document and claims everything is "common sense". Common sense I'm sure varies from person to person in an opinionated field like software development, that's why documents and team rules exist. But they don't have one and it's hard for me to guess what they want.

I see even longer reviews (90+ comments) happening to other people for a relatively simple feature but it doesn't seem to stress them out for some reason, and no one else is complaining about the process.

So my question is, is this how code review usually happens in a big "tech" company (not FAANG)?

And how do I deal with it?

Would it be wise to bring up my frustrations with the manager, or confront coworkers directly?

The manager is very hands off, it seems he doesn't like to impose any hard rules. I want to bring it up but don't know how to do it without rocking the boat, because I am the newest person on the team.

One solution might be to discuss every thing with coworkers before I write any code, but I fear they will say I can't work independently. I just want the PR review to go smoother instead of it seeming like I can't code at all due to 20+ comments.

P.S. Changing teams/jobs is not an option right now due to visa reasons.

Comment: Do you have retros where you could raise this?

Comment: We don't have retros, we only have sprint planning sessions and standups every other day

Comment: @Joe Strazzere Yes, I can seek help for mental health but I think that doesn't solve the cause of the problem which is the PR review process right?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere well it could be that those people are not stressed because they don't know any better, they think it's normal because this is the only company they ever worked at.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere btw I edited the title

Comment: Why is changing jobs not an option?

Comment: And the downvotes are likely because this comes more as a rant than an actual question as my guess

Comment: How long have you been at this company? What was on-boarding like? What has your manager said about this?

Comment: Who is leaving the comments? Do they have any authority, or could you just say "thanks for commenting, I'll leave it as it is"?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul it's not option for visa reasons. I didn't mean to rant but I guess I am pretty frustrated it came across that way.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, and well, i recommend editing out the question to focus down to fact and issues, including down the visa thing. Then its much easier to provide a solid answer.

Comment: @AakashM A few months. The onboarding was only 30% helpful for day to day work but the reviews aren't related to what I learned in onboarding, more like coworkers' different opinions for code and design. However the team has no best practices document. The manager told me to chill. I am seriously stressed though because these peer reviews are so inefficient it takes a long time to get anything done.

Comment: To answer your edit on downvotes: This question has no real goal this community can address. The community is not a place for "advice" questions, and the downvotes reflect that condition. There's also an element here of specific "company policy" that's at play as well. (note: I didn't downvote, though I did vote to close for one of these reasons)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like there's a pretty big communication problem lurking underneath. PRs should be a straightforward thing, either they're good (maybe with a slight adjustment) or they are not acceptable, in which case there should be a constructive face-to-face discussion about the perceived problems, not a fierce game of comment racquets.

If your colleagues prefer to obstruct integration of your PRs instead of talking to you, you should talk to your manager. This behavior is leading to reduced productivity and increasing team tension, which is something they should not ignore.

It is possible that you're part of the problem (communication always involves 2 or more parties), and you should be open to adjust your own behavior, too, not just look at other's "mis"behavior. A good manager might have some insight and may be able to give feedback about the way you're coming across to others. Even if you don't have an insightful manager, it might be a good idea to start talking to the colleagues with whom you're supposed to work in a team.

Answer (score 3):

#### This is a management problem

You should expect that code review is done against a set of standards.  Reviews done against the standard of "it's common sense" means there isn't a standard.  So the company has a process based on peers setting standards based on how they feel about the code, and the only way to learn what these feeling-based standards are is by getting review comments.  Every time the review is made, different things can be reviewed since there really isn't a standard.

My opinion is you should talk to your manager about the development processes at the company.  I don't see how anyone could think what you're describing is a good idea, but maybe they either just don't know how to fix it, or the organizational inertia is too large to allow change.  Regardless, your manager can talk you through how to navigate the environment.  You can then choose whether this works for you or if you should seek other organizations for employment.

Comment: Yeah, the OP's team definitely needs to formalize a standard. It's likely that none of them will be completely happy with all of it, but they just need to be prepared to stick to it.